# How to have these 2 matrices side by side

Tags: matrices

In fact I want to have these two matrices side by side, here is the code:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[10pt]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\usepackage[thin, , thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\usepackage[hmargin=2.6 cm,vmargin=3.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}


\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mfrac{A}{B} &  E & \mfrac{C}{D} & 0 \\
-K &  \mfrac{-Z}{Y} & T & \mfrac{W}{V} \\
\mfrac{XY}{MOP}& -\mfrac{US}{TV} & \mfrac{1}{B}(\mfrac{MN}{AB}-\mfrac{LA} 
{BC}) & RR \\
\mfrac{A}{B} & \mfrac{C}{D} & -E & \mfrac{1}{C}(\mfrac{DE}{GH}-\mfrac{IJ} 
{KL})  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 2
\end{bmatrix}
 =
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & A & 0 & 0\\
\mfrac{AA}{BB} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{CCr} & 0 \\ 
0 & \mfrac{-DE}{BCD} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{FG} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just replace `\end{aling*} \begin{align*}` between these equations by `,\quad`.

Comment: I didn't understand @marmot

Comment: Try `\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mfrac{A}{B} &  E & \mfrac{C}{D} & 0 \\
-K &  \mfrac{-Z}{Y} & T & \mfrac{W}{V} \\
\mfrac{XY}{MOP}& -\mfrac{US}{TV} & \mfrac{1}{B}(\mfrac{MN}{AB}-\mfrac{LA} 
{BC}) & RR \\
\mfrac{A}{B} & \mfrac{C}{D} & -E & \mfrac{1}{C}(\mfrac{DE}{GH}-\mfrac{IJ} 
{KL})  \\
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
 2
\end{bmatrix}
 =
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & A & 0 & 0\\
\mfrac{AA}{BB} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{CCr} & 0 \\ 
0 & \mfrac{-DE}{BCD} & 0 & \mfrac{1}{FG} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}` ...

Comment: ... it is however unclear to me whether it is really better to write `\begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}` as opposed to simply `[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

very similar to what suggested [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)in his comments above:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.6 cm,
            vmargin=3.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, nccmath}

\begin{document}
\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
[1] = \begin{bmatrix}
        \mfrac{A}{B}    &  E                & \mfrac{C}{D}  & 0 \\
                -K      &  \mfrac{-Z}{Y}    & T             & \mfrac{W}{V} \\
        \mfrac{XY}{MOP} & -\mfrac{US}{TV}   & \mfrac{1}{B}\left(\mfrac{MN}{AB}-\mfrac{LA}{BC}\right)
                                                            & RR \\
        \mfrac{A}{B}    & \mfrac{C}{D}      & -E            & \mfrac{1}{C}\left(\mfrac{DE}{GH}-\mfrac{IJ}{KL}\right)  \\
\end{bmatrix},
    \qquad
[2] = \begin{bmatrix}
        A               & 0                 & 0                 & 0 \\
        0               & A                 & 0                 & 0 \\
        \mfrac{AA}{BB}  & 0                 & \mfrac{1}{CCr}    & 0 \\
        0               & \mfrac{-DE}{BCD}  & 0                 & \mfrac{1}{FG}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

[image]